# error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later. When decompiling MCP

Tags: java, macos, minecraft, decompiler

Im trying to decompile the MCP v1.8.8 on mac but when I run the decompile.sh file I get this error:

```
error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

If i look in eclipse > Client the folder is empty so i cant do anything

Here is the complete log

```
codergautam@Coders-Air mcp918 % bash decompile.sh                                     
== MCP 9.18 (data: 9.18, client: 1.8.8, server: 1.8.8) ==
"scalac" is not found on the PATH.  Scala files will not be recompiled
# found ff, ff patches, srgs, name csvs, doc csvs, param csvs, astyle, astyle config, rg, ss
Looking in /Users/codergautam/Library/Application Support/minecraft/versions for mc installs... OK
Copying assets... OK
Parsing JSON file... OK
Looking for minecraft main jar... Not found
Copying minecraft main jar... OK
> Checking libraries...
    Copying library jinput... OK
    Copying library lwjgl-platform... OK
    Copying library icu4j-core-mojang... OK
    Copying library httpcore... OK
    Copying library log4j-api... OK
    Copying library commons-lang3... OK
    Copying library jna... OK
    Copying library libraryjavasound... OK
    Copying library jopt-simple... OK
    Copying library guava... OK
    Copying library oshi-core... OK
    Copying library httpclient... OK
    Copying library commons-compress... OK
    Copying library platform... OK
    Copying library codecjorbis... OK
    Copying library soundsystem... OK
    Copying library librarylwjglopenal... OK
    Copying library lwjgl_util... OK
    Copying library commons-codec... OK
    Copying library jutils... OK
    Copying library commons-logging... OK
    Copying library lwjgl... OK
    Copying library commons-io... OK
    Copying library realms... OK
    Copying library authlib... OK
    Copying library gson... OK
    Copying library netty... OK
    Copying library twitch... OK
    Copying library codecwav... OK
    Copying library twitch-platform... OK
    Copying library jinput-platform... OK
    Copying library log4j-core... OK
    Copying library netty-all... OK
> Checking Natives...
    Extracting native libtwitchsdk.dylib... OK
    Extracting native liblwjgl.dylib... OK
    Extracting native libjinput-osx.jnilib... OK
    Extracting native openal.dylib... OK
== Decompiling client using fernflower ==
> Creating SRGs
> Applying SpecialSource
> Applying MCInjector
> Creating renamed srg
> Filtering classes
> Decompiling
> Unpacking jar
> Copying sources
> Applying fernflower fixes
> Applying patches
'patch -p1 -u -i ../../temp/temp.patch -d src/minecraft' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file net/minecraft/util/Cartesian.java.rej
==================

> Cleaning comments
- Done in 111.82 seconds
== Reformating client ==
> Cleaning sources
> Replacing OpenGL constants
> Reformating sources
- Done in 6.95 seconds
== Updating client ==
> Adding javadoc
> Renaming sources
- Done in 1.52 seconds
== Decompiling server using fernflower ==
> Creating SRGs
> Applying SpecialSource
> Applying MCInjector
> Creating renamed srg
> Filtering classes
> Decompiling
> Unpacking jar
> Copying sources
> Applying fernflower fixes
> Applying patches
'patch -p1 -u -i ../../temp/temp.patch -d src/minecraft_server' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file net/minecraft/util/Cartesian.java.rej
==================

> Cleaning comments
- Done in 51.87 seconds
== Reformating server ==
> Cleaning sources
> Reformating sources
- Done in 4.44 seconds
== Updating server ==
> Adding javadoc
> Renaming sources
- Done in 1.03 seconds
== Recompiling client ==
> Cleaning bin
> Recompiling
'"javac" -Xlint:-options -deprecation -g -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -classpath "jars/versions/1.8.8/1.8.8.jar:lib:lib/*:jars/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput/2.0.5/jinput-2.0.5.jar:jars/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.2-nightly-20140822/lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-nightly-20140822-natives-osx.jar:jars/libraries/com/ibm/icu/icu4j-core-mojang/51.2/icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar:jars/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar:jars/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.0-beta9/log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar:jars/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:jars/libraries/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar:jars/libraries/com/paulscode/libraryjavasound/20101123/libraryjavasound-20101123.jar:jars/libraries/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.6/jopt-simple-4.6.jar:jars/libraries/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.jar:jars/libraries/oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar:jars/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.jar:jars/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar:jars/libraries/net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar:jars/libraries/com/paulscode/codecjorbis/20101023/codecjorbis-20101023.jar:jars/libraries/com/paulscode/soundsystem/20120107/soundsystem-20120107.jar:jars/libraries/com/paulscode/librarylwjglopenal/20100824/librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar:jars/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.2-nightly-20140822/lwjgl_util-2.9.2-nightly-20140822.jar:jars/libraries/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar:jars/libraries/net/java/jutils/jutils/1.0.0/jutils-1.0.0.jar:jars/libraries/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:jars/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.2-nightly-20140822/lwjgl-2.9.2-nightly-20140822.jar:jars/libraries/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:jars/libraries/com/mojang/realms/1.7.39/realms-1.7.39.jar:jars/libraries/com/mojang/authlib/1.5.21/authlib-1.5.21.jar:jars/libraries/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar:jars/libraries/com/mojang/netty/1.6/netty-1.6.jar:jars/libraries/tv/twitch/twitch/6.5/twitch-6.5.jar:jars/libraries/com/paulscode/codecwav/20101023/codecwav-20101023.jar:jars/libraries/tv/twitch/twitch-platform/6.5/twitch-platform-6.5-natives-osx.jar:jars/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar:jars/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.0-beta9/log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar:jars/libraries/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.23.Final/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar" -sourcepath src/minecraft -d bin/minecraft @temp/java_src_client.txt' failed : 2

== ERRORS FOUND in JAVA CODE ==

error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
==================

Initial client recompile failed, correct source then run updatemd5
== Recompiling server ==
> Cleaning bin
> Recompiling
'"javac" -Xlint:-options -deprecation -g -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -classpath "lib:lib/*:jars/minecraft_server.jar" -sourcepath src/minecraft_server -d bin/minecraft_server @temp/java_src_server.txt' failed : 2

== ERRORS FOUND in JAVA CODE ==

error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
==================

Initial server recompile failed, correct source then run updatemd5
codergautam@Coders-Air mcp918 %
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the decompiled code was in the src folder

Dragging the contents from that into the Client folder worked

I have no idea why it didn't decompile into the Eclipse folder